# WSO2 Identity Server ver 4.0 - SAML SSO credentials to route to custom API for validation

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Have following questions regarding WSO2 Identity Server ver 4.0:

Would like to know if it is possible to route the SAML single signon credentials to third party API for validation i.e. user would type in the credential at the WSO2 SAML single signon screen and the credential  to be sent to my custom API for validation and once validated will come back to the consumer, configured in the WSO2 carbon server.

how to launch WSO2 Identity server from eclipse. Am using indigo flavor.

Answer (score 0):

On the second question of launching identity server form Eclipse, you can use the WSO2 Developer Studio plug-in with Eclipse and start the identity server as a Cabon server instance. [See developer studio docs for more](http://dist.wso2.org/products/developer-studio/2.1.0/docs/) information